# Graphical software to sync an FTP folder and a local folder

Tags: linux, open-source, file-synchronization, ftp

I have a website hosted on an FTP server.

After I modify the website's source code, I want to push it, but I have to be careful because data is generated dynamically, and sometimes my colleagues modify files directly on the server, so I can't just push blindly.

I am looking for an app that would show me the differences and let me choose what to copy left and right.

[Capivara](http://capivara.sourceforge.net/) sounded like the perfect solution but unfortunately it marks files as different if their timestamp is different, so all files are different:

[image: Capivara]

Is there a similar app that would ignore timestamps and consider files as identical if they have the **same data content**? I don't mind all files being downloaded at every sync for checksum calculation, as it is not big.

Requirements:

- Can run on Linux
- Open source
- Graphical interface to easily see the differences and merge

Comment: Actually the process of the workflow seems fragile, I would use some control system if there are multiple users contributing to a single project, still if you don't like that for some reason, filezilla has inbuilt file comparison module where you can compare he files by the size, date of file modified etc... I can provide an answer of filezilla but I feel that am understanding your question in some wrong way... so correct me if am wrong...

Comment: I agree that sounds like a very risky workflow. so I'm wondering how much control of the server do you have? (i.e. could you install git to it and use that instead? - it would be much much safer; and if you are okay with that significant of an adjustment to your workflow and have  sufficient server adjustment ability I can provide instructions for it as an answer.

Comment: We try to use Git as much as possible, but sometimes someone breaks the rule and modifies directly, which I agree is bad. Actually you can see in my screenshot that the local directory is managed by Git. We have zero control on the server, only FTP access.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul For which operating system?

Comment: @moose: Sorry I forgot to mention it! Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

As I told you that workflow is fragile, personally I've different approach which depends on types of work, also in comments, I recommended you Git, but not everyone can use that for Private Repository without having a premium account.

The best you can try here is [FtpVC](http://www.prestosoft.com/fvc_ftpvc.asp) *(For Windows, but we can use Wine)*, the features of the software generally matches your requirements....

> FtpVC (FTP Version Control) is a **serverless version control system** for
>   Windows, which allows **joint software development** using Internet FTP
>   connections. FtpVC provides all basic version control features that
>   are necessary for any **collaborative development**, allowing users from
>   all over the world to jointly and safely work on the same project
>   without the possibility of conflict, with very little setup. FtpVC is
>   a Windows client but an FTP server can be run on any platform.

**Features**

- Does not require a version control server - uses standard FTP protocol.
- Allows you to get, check out, check in, undo check out, and label files.
- Maintains file revision history.
- Allows to set watch for a specific file (so that email notifications are sent on version control events).
- Shows differences between different file versions.
- Supports SMTP servers with authentication.
- Supports multiple version control projects.
- Provides recursive file management.
- Allows compression and encryption of remote files.
- Includes standard FTP client features (put, delete, rename, move files and directories, create directories).

[Click here](http://www.prestosoft.com/fvc_screenshots.asp) for Screenshots.

Comment: Comparing with filesize and modification time does not sound very reliable... time is different on server and clients, and some files might get modified without changing in size. The directory is not big so I don't mind if all files are downloaded at each sync to calculate their checksum.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Edited the answer...

Comment: Looks interesting! Does FtpVC store any of its metadata (locks/etc) on the FTP server beside the real data?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Everything should be local as far as I know...

Comment: FtpVC doesn’t seem to be Open Source, or did I miss something?

Comment: @unor check the edits of the OP :)